# XMLRPC: How to retrieve possible custom fields for a new post?

Tags: api, xml-rpc, wp-api

I'm planning to implement certain XMLRPC elements in my external web application. If I'm passing [wp.newPost](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost) as the method, how can I get the possible custom_fields?

I don't have access to the WordPress files themselves (because the application will serve users which I don't want to force to download or adjust files.)

I know I can pass the custom fields by key:value pairs, but what I want is first display the list of keys to the user of the application.

Comment: Just wondering why you wouldn't use the REST API?

Comment: @vancoder as I understand, the JSON REST API is yet to be fully implemented. The foundation was added to WP 4.4 but not the actual endpoints. I don't want to require users to use a plugin, and I don't want to rely on WP's Core team's schedule since that's something out of my control.